# Kubernetes Haproxy Ingress controller external ip restrict access

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy-ingress

I'm using ExternalIps for Haproxy Ingress Controller. What other ways to restrict (ip whitelist) access to Haproxy Ingress Controller besides whitelist in haproxy?

Comment: Would you explain a little further your environment? Why IP Whitelist is not suitable for you? What kind of filtering do you need to implement?

Comment: client certificate authentication is also an option

Comment: Whitelist is not working in https ssl passthrough. I've already created ticket for it. It also has problems with long lists. I've create  confgimap and maped it to file. When i update file I should trigger update by maxcon++ in configmap of controller. It seems not very good solution for me.